# Push notification on production mode

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, apple-push-notifications

I am new to iOS and Push notification. My PNS is working good on development mode now i want to do it for production purpose.

Plase guide me all the procedure for doing on production mode. Also how can i test Push notification is received or not on Production mode.??

Belo code working good in devlopment mode...

```
#pragma mark - Push Notifications Methods

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString *tokenStr = [deviceToken description];

    // Separete Your device token with <,< and blanksapace
    NSString *pushToken = [[[tokenStr
                              stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"  withString:@""]
                              stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">"  withString:@""]
                              stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "  withString:@""];

    sclass.deviceToken = pushToken;
    // Save the token to server
    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.vijaywebsolutions.com/Development_FTP/webservice/webservices.php?deviceToken=%@",pushToken]; // Passing token to URL
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self]; // Support to perform URLrequest

    if( theConnection )// checking connection successfull or not
    {
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSLog(@"device token is %@", pushToken);
    }
}

 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) // If app is running and you got notification then show it 
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Did receive a Remote Notification" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Have a Notification :\n%@",userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"]]delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }

    NSLog(@"Payload: %@", userInfo);
    imageURL =  userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"];
    MainViewController *MvC=[[MainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainViewControlleripad" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController=MvC;
    [MvC  sshowansimage:imageURL];
}
```

Comment: Are you using proper provisioning for production environment?

Comment: No i have not created any profile for production mode. need all gudline pls help

Comment: can give step by step procedure for prodiction mode

Comment: Check this simple guide - http://quickblox.com/developers/How_to_create_APNS_certificates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to test the production push notification service, create an Adhoc distribution profile for your app in provisioning profile. Download profile and install. Choose the Adhoc dist profile to code sign your app. Archive ipa and save for adhoc distribution. Add the ipa to your device and test push. It will use production push certs as opposed to development cert.

For creating production push certificates, you follow exactly the same procedure as for development but you select production (not sandboxed) certificates in the apple dev portal.

Comment: no still not working PNS receives in devmode but not in production mode i have folloed all proceudre

Answer (score 2):

You need distributed provision file to test the product mode. 
Product -> Archive -> Distribute -> Save for enterprise or Ad hoc -> next and choose distributed provision file. Then install the ipa file. **You can only do this if your iphone has been jailbreak.**

If not, you need no worry about the product mode if you passed the development mode test. Just replace the apns url to the product mode and all be wright.